# Testing that a child's method has been overloaded

Tags: c++, testing

In a large codebase, we had the following issue:

Class A contains method1(a, b, c)

Class B inherites from A, and contains method1(a, b, c) (overload of the one in A)

The problem appeared when a new default parameter was added to method1 of class A, but:

- it was not added to method1 of class B;
- B.method1(...) thus called method1 of class A (parent).

The fix was simple, as the new parameter was added to B's method.

I would like to write a unit test that checks that B's method and A's method have the exact same number of paramaters (i.e., B's method should always be updated).

Do you have any ideas about how I could do that?

Note: no c++11.

Here is a similar code of my case:

Header:

```
class Parent:
{
 public:
  virtual bool method(int a, int b, int c=1);
};

class Child: public Parent
{
 public:
  virtual bool method(int a, int b);
};
```

cpp:

```
class Parent:
{
  boot method(int a, int b, int c)
  {
...
  }
}

class Child:
{
  boot method(int a, int b)
  {
...
  }
}
```

As the code is not updated yet in a first time to use 3 arguments, we still call Child.method(a, b), without the third argument.

Later on, it will break the code, but my purpose is simply to ensure that both methods always have the same number/type of arguments.

Comment: Unit tests are about ensuring things function as they are intended, not about how they go about performing their function. Argument comparisons feels more about how they perform their function.

Comment: If a unit-test fails to compile, couldn't that be seen as the ultimate failure of the test?

Comment: Can you show the actual code? The overload in `B` should normally hide the overload in `A`, so `A`'s overload shouldn't be easily accessible when referring through type `B` in the first place.

Comment: A unit test not compiling is fine, and shows that something is wrong.

Comment: @Angew: actually, as the signature is different (one argument is missing), the parent methods are then checked, one method is found, and called. That's normal behaviour.

Comment: @Jiehong No, that's not normal behaviour.

Comment: Don't try and unit test for sloppy programming. "You can't immunise against assault and battery"

Comment: @Jiehong No, they're not. Name hiding takes place when the set of overloaded functions is constructed, and only after that does overload resolution take place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assert(&method != &Parent::method);
```

Something like that? I didn't try it.

Comment: Was about to suggest that, but in his case it should be !=

Comment: This simply breaks the compilation of the tests, because of different types. This seems to be a pretty good solution.

Comment: Note that the correct way is `(&Child::method != &Parent::method)` (else you have `ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&Child::method' [-fpermissive]`).

Comment: That won't work if you have overload methods, as it will be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Just the following fails to compile as
`bool method(int a, int b)` hides `bool method(int a, int b, int c)`  : https://ideone.com/rf4TU5

```
Child child;

child.method(1, 2, 3);
```

A possibility to check that a class verify a certain interface:

```
#define DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(traitsName, funcName, signature)       \
    template <typename U>                                           \
    class traitsName                                                \
    {                                                               \
    private:                                                        \
        template<typename T, T> struct helper;                      \
        template<typename T>                                        \
        static char check(helper<signature, &funcName>*);           \
        template<typename T> static char (&check(...))[2];          \
    public:                                                         \
        static                                                      \
        const bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(char);     \
    }

DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(has_method_2, T::method, bool (T::*)(int, int));
DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(has_method_3, T::method, bool (T::*)(int, int, int));

// Aggregate all requirements for Interface
template <typename T>
struct check_Parent_Interface
{
    static const bool value = !has_method_2<T>::value && has_method_3<T>::value;
};
```

And in your tests, check : https://ideone.com/pPitVq

```
EXPECTED(true, check_Parent_Interface<Parent>::value);
EXPECTED(true, check_Parent_Interface<Child>::value);
```

Comment: Yes, but the dev. was into 1 parts: the global part contained the classes, and the used code was not updated yet, so it was only using `child.method(1, 2)`.
I'll update the question to include that part.

Comment: @Jiehong In that case, it couldn't have possibly been calling the parent member function.

Comment: The only problem is that you must update the macro when you change the signature. The purpose of the test would be to tell you that you forgot to update that signature on the child side. I'll go with Neil Kirk's answers. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jiehong: You change the `CheckParentInterface` only when you change its interface, which seems correct. The test are untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Your test sounds more like a smoke-test then an actual unit test imo.

If you already do smoke testing on your code, you could add a test that does a diff on the function definition of method1 in the header files of A and B and see if they are similar enough (exact match, exact match after strip spaces/tabs, same number of commas...).